# Reference request: Lie group theory with emphasis on Riemannian geometry

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

I was hoping there is a textbook focused on Lie groups that has particular focus on the Riemannian geometry side of Lie groups: Left-invariant, bi-invariant metrics, relationship between the Lie and manifold exponential maps, left-invariant affine connections, the Cartan connection on Lie groups, etc. To my knowledge, although there are some great textbooks on Lie groups out there, I haven't found any that really focus on the Riemannian geometry properties of Lie groups. They usually introduce Lie groups, focus on their algebraic properties, talk about the Lie exponential, Lie algebra, classification. At least in my experience, nearly every textbook on Lie groups focus entirely on their algebraic properties.

The best I have found is the chapter on Lie groups in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds. Of course, this is only a chapter. I'd appreciate a whole textbook about this.

Comment: How about *An Introduction to Lie Groups and the Geometry of Homogeneous Spaces* by Arvanitoyeorgos?

Comment: You can check out *Differential Geometry and Lie Groups: A Second Course* and *Differential Geometry and Lie Groups: A Computational Perspective* by Jean Gallier/Jocelyn Quaintance.

Comment: I strongly recommend Helgason’s [classic](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/34).

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you, this seems to be what I am looking for from the table of contents. Always would appreciate more suggestions too!

Comment: @TedShifrin I only read the table of contents, but this seems to be more algebra-focused than Riemannian geometry-focused. Am I incorrect saying that maybe?

Comment: There's plenty of Riemannian geometry in there. For example, he has my favorite proof of the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem (which is not, per se, a theorem about Lie groups).